# qTip2 with html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm having some trouble getting popups with html content to work using [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). The popup that is displayed is blank and I'm not sure why.

Here is my javascript:

```
$('.tooltip').qtip({
    content: {
        text: function(api){
            $(this).next('.tooltip-content');
        }
    }
});​
```

And my html is:

```
<a class="tooltip"></a>
<div class="tooltip-content"><strong>this is some tooltip</strong> content. <em>italic</em></div>​
```

I have set up a jsfiddle showing my problem - **http://jsfiddle.net/tajsy/**

I plan to have lots of these tooltips on one page so I would like to pair up the link and the hidden div with the content for it.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle with working qtip references, but the demo just shows an empty bubble. Why? http://jsfiddle.net/tajsy/192/

Comment: I'm not really sure - it has been a long time since I used it. qTip2 seems to be a dead project now https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/issues/835

Comment: if it's dead, what should be used instead?

Comment: I haven't had to use tooltips in any of my recent work so I can't really answer that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using a function, you need to return the element:

```
 text: function(api){
     return $(this).next('.tooltip-content');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

qtip2 Inline HTML 
http://jsfiddle.net/uaR3m/20/

```
 $('a').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
         content: {
             text: function(api){
             return $($(this).attr('href'));
             }

         }
     });
 });
```